# Show the following sequence is Cauchy: $x_n = \frac{\cos 1} 3 + \frac{\cos 3}{ 3 ^2} +\cdots+ \frac{\cos(2n−1)}{3^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

this is my answer, is it wrong?
$$|x_n-x_m|= \left|\frac{\cos(n+1)}{3^{n+1}}+\cdots+ \frac{\cos(2m-1)}{3^m}\right|
\\\leq\frac1{3^{n+1}} +\cdots+ \frac 1{3^m} + \frac 1{3^{m+1}} = \frac1{3^n} < \epsilon $$
$n_0$ $\frac1{2^{n_0} }< \epsilon$  so for all $n \geq n_0$
has this innequality  $\frac1{2^n }\leq\epsilon$
so by sequence it's Cauchy.

Comment: It’s not clear to me why you have the term $\frac1{3^{m+1}}$ nor why you have $=\frac1{3^n}.$

Comment: You should definitely note that this is for $n<m.$

Comment: Also, the first term should be $\frac{\cos(2n+1)}{3^{n+1}}.$

Comment: Taking into account comments from Mr. Thomas Andrews, note that sum of finite many terms of G.P. (with all terms positive) is less than sum of infinitely many terms of G.P. on right hand side to prove the statement.

Comment: Yes, this is a good start. The answer needs more details.

Comment: It’s unclear why you chose $\frac1{2^{n_0}}$ rather than $\frac1{3^{n_0}},$ but it will work, too.